# Why a image from database is not showing in the table?

Tags: jquery, image, html-table

[image: Output]

It is my code in jQuery: after appending data still image is not working. Did I make a mistake with that object imgs:

[image: Database table]

```
CallWebService: function() {

    var webMethod = "http://localhost:30101/Api/MoviesAPI/GetMoviesList";
    $.getJSON(webMethod, function (data) {
        var myhtml = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            debugger;
            var imgs ="<img src='@Url.Content(item.pictures)' alt='Test' width='60' height='100' />";

            myhtml += '<tr>';
            myhtml += '<td>' + item.moviesID + '</td>';
            myhtml += '<td>' + item.title + '</td>';
            myhtml += '<td>' + item.language + '</td>';
            myhtml += '<td>' + item.genre + '</td>';
            myhtml += '<td>' + imgs  + '</td>';
            myhtml += '<td>' + item.documents + '</td>';
            myhtml += '<td> <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyAddEditform" ';
            myhtml += 'id="btnEdit"  class="btnEdit btn btn-group-sm btn-primary">';
            myhtml += ' Edit</button><button type="button" id="btnDelete" ';
            myhtml += 'class="btnDelete btn  btn-group-sm btn-danger"> Delete</button>' + '</td>' + '</tr>';
        });
        $("#myTable").append(myhtml);
```

Comment: what you have inside item.pictures?

Comment: try to replace this : `'@Url.Content(item.pictures)'` to this `"@Url.Content(item.pictures)"` and show us what `@Url.Content(item.pictures)` return please